# Fields of SQLAlchemy models filled after creating new object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a Python application using the Flask framework with SQLAlchemy and now struggling with a strange behavior on creating new model objects.

Lets say I have a model Offer which has some fields, a private property `__validation_errors` and a public method `validate`:

```
from app import db

class Offer(db.Model):
    currency = db.Column(db.String(255))
    price = db.Column(db.Numeric(20, 5))
    __validation_errors = []

    def validate(self, errors: List[Exception]) -> bool:
        self.validate_not_empty()
        self.validate_price()
        for err in self.__validation_errors:
            errors.append(err)
        if len(self.__validation_errors) > 0:
            return False
        return True
```

the object itself is created in a service class by calling

```
offer = Offer(currency, price)
```

and providing data received with a POST request in a router.
If the validation fails, an error message is returned to the user and the object is not written into DB.

And here begins the strange part. If a request with invalid data is received and another request with correct data is sent, the values in the __validation_errors list don't disappear in the offer object, like if the object is reused and not reset. If another invalid request is made, the errors are just appended to the already existing in the list. Of course, it can be fixed by setting `__validation_errors = []` every time the `validate()` method is called, but I would like to understand what is happening here. Do I miss some SQLAlchemy specific features? The app.db object and the Session are created on app and exist all the time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is your issue, but because `__validation_errors` is part of the class declaration, and it isn't replaced (just `append`ed to), the `self.__validation_errors` will be the same as `Offer.__validation_errors` (ie it is shared between all instances of the class). You may want to create it in the `__init__` method, like: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs); self.__validation_errors = []`

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty thanks for your reply. I am pretty new to Python and probably not familiar enough with class declarations. If its really the case, that the properties declared in the class are shared if not set explicitely, than it should be it... I solved it by setting it to [] before the validation methods are called. Setting it to [] in `__init__` would do it probably as well.

Comment: Yeah, so anything declared/created in the body of the `class ...:` is part of the class itself, like static variables in C / Java. Whereas with C / Java you're declaring the attributes each instance will have (since the compiler needs to know the size of each class in memory). It kind of makes sense when you think about the fact that functions are objects in python, and so by putting them in the class declaration they're methods shared between all instances.

Comment: And it's not so much that you're explicitly setting them otherwise, but that you're replacing the reference to the class attribute with a reference to an instance attribute (you should look up python pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference for an idea of why resetting __validation_errors fixed it [made it an instance attribute rather than a class attribute], if you're not already familiar with it)

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty,  Thanks. The last two things are known, but didn't know about sharing the methods and attributes being shared between the instances. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trouble here is that `__validation_errors` is bound to the *class* `Offer`, rather than an instance of `Offer`, which means that unless each instance sets its own `self.__validation_errors`, `self.__validation_errors` just maps to `Offer.__validation_errors` for every instance (kind of like accessing an attribute/function of a subclass that only exists on the parent class).

Take for example:

```py
>>> class SomeClass:
...     some_list = []
... 
>>> a = SomeClass()
>>> b = SomeClass()
>>> a.some_list.append(5)
>>> a.some_list
[5]
>>> b.some_list
[5]
>>> a.some_list is b.some_list
True
```

This is because anything in the class body is an attribute of the class itself (this makes a little more sense considering the fact that methods are also class attributes - unlike in prototype-based languages), rather than a value each instance is assigned after it is created

```py
>>> class SomeClass:
...     x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
...
>>> SomeClass.x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> SomeClass().x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> SomeClass.x is SomeClass().x
True
```

If you want to bind the attribute to the instance rather than the class, you attach it to `self`, preferably in `__init__`

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
```

---

PS, it's worth noting that this is only really noticeable when you're working with mutable attributes. With immutable attributes, any "change" will create a new value on the object, and since `<instance>.<attribute>` is retrieved instead of `<instance>.__class__.<attribute>` whenever it exists, it will appear that the instance was separate from the class to begin with.

---

So, back to your example, I'd suggest initializing `__validation_errors` at the same time you `__init__`ialize the rest of the object:

```py
class Offer(db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__validation_errors = []

    def validate(self, errors: List[Exception]) -> bool:
        ...
```